# Scaling problems (using drivers or hooks)

Tags: drivers

I want to do a wooden construction within Blender 2.79. The width of the beams shall be variable (for example using a driver) but identical for all beams.

My problem is that the position of the beams need to change according to the width of the beams.

An example:
[image: Inital Setup - working]

The image shows two vertical and two horizontal beams. The x- and y-scale of the beams is controlled via a driver via the x-scale of the selected "Reference" cube.

When increasing the scale of the cube, the beams will intersect as shown in the next screenshot:[image: Driven - not working anymore]
*Note that the expression for my driver is contained in this screenshot as well.*

Again, imagine this is a real wooden construction: the top horizontal beam is too short and too low, the second one is too wide.

I tried to control the Z-position of the horizontal beams with a driver as well, but I needed to include the current Z-position of the beam plus "Scale Factor/2" which is a recursive expression and therefore makes no sense.

I tried to solve this problem with hooks as well, but to no avail.

Any ideas on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated - if I don't need drivers or hooks: even better!

Thanks in advance
blackno666

The .blend file is [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49811).

Comment: I can't entirely understand your goal or your problem.  However, I wonder if setting the origin of the beam to one of its corners rather than its center would help you?  When you do that, the model will end up scaling about the fixed corner, rather than its center.

Comment: Scaling the objects is the wrong approach. Use shapekeys and an array modifier. See if the ladder sample [here](http://exploreblender.com) provides enough info for you to figure it out.